# FCM delivers duplicated copies of Push Notifications

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using fcm node modules to send push notifications. Tried to send to a group(group with one device token).  And all it delivers duplicated copies(4 copies everytime) of the same push for a single alert. It was supposed to be delivered only one. I have used [fcm-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node) (version: 1.2.1), [fcm-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push) (version: 1.1.3) etc.

The **nodejs** code is as shown below:

```
Alerts.pushTry = function (cb) {
          var serverKey = "abcd"; //put your server key here
          var deviceToken = 'group_key'; // required

        var FCM = require('fcm-node');

        var message = { //this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera)
            to: deviceToken, 
            notification: {
                title: 'Group 555 test'+ ((new Date()).getTime()), 
                body: 'Body of your push notification' 
            },

            data: {
                my_key: 'my value',
                my_another_key: 'my another value'
            }
        };

        fcm.send(message, function(err, response) {
            console.log("sent");
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
                cb(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
                cb(null, response);
            }
        });

    };
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: i also face this issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, I have used the request module and connected the fcm push notification url directly without depending these types of npm modules with open issues.

Comment: can you show me how you do that .i.e code

Comment: var request = require('request');

Comment: request({ url: 'fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';, method: "POST", headers: { "content-type" : "application/json", "Authorization": key=${constants.FCM_SERVER_KEY}, "project_id": constants.FCM_SENDER_ID, }, json: message }, function(error, response, body) {});

Answer (score 0):

There are some open issues exists for the above mentioned node modules.. I have used the request module and connected the fcm push notification url directly without depending on these types of npm modules with open issues.

```
var request = require('request');
    request({ 
        url: 'fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        method: "POST", 
        headers: { "content-type" : "application/json", 
        "Authorization": key=${constants.FCM_SERVER_KEY}, 
        "project_id": constants.FCM_SENDER_ID, }, 
        json: message 
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        //You code
    });
```

Comment: I have duplicated notification with https api also